# How to exit UITabBarController and go to another Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

[image: illustrate image]

I have a `TabBarController`, and one of the tab item is a `NavigationController`, and inside the `NavigationController` is a `TableView`. If press the cell, it will go to another `ViewController`. And inside that `ViewController`, there is a back button on the `NavigationBar`(apparently), and if i press that button, i can go back to the `TableView`.
The question is, after i go to the last `ViewController`, how can i get rid of the tab Bar, and when i press the back button and go back to the `TableView`, the tab Bar will still be there.
Btw, i'm coding with swift, so please give me some direction on swift rather than object-c. thanks

Comment: You can use the accepted answer in this. Just put it in viewWillAppear or something.

Comment: there is another possibility than the one provided in the already answered thread: select the viewcontroller in storyboard where you want the tabbar to disappear (the last one in the hierarchy) and in the attributes inspector check "Hide Bottom Bar on Push"!

Comment: @AndréSlotta I believe that does the same thing but embedded inside the segue. But yes, would be easier to do this if you're already in a Storyboard.

Comment: @Fogmeister that's possible. Except there is no code needed :) just wanted to provide "an alternative"...

Comment: @AndréSlotta I agree :D